# How to get to long directory quickly when writting code in VIM

Tags: vim

I am writing Bash script using VIM. I need to cd to a directory and run the command tool. The command tool is deep inside the directory. How do I quickly cd to that directory instead of manually typing the directory out in VIM ? In terminal prompt, I can get to the directory quickly using tab. It does not work in VIM.

Thanks

ffl3883

Comment: Perhaps you need [`CTRL-X CTRL-F`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F) in Insert mode?

Comment: Vim `cd` also supports `tab` for me. (vim8.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can change to the currently edited file's directory with `:cd %:h`; see [`:help filename-modifiers`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#filename-modifiers). Likewise, if you trigger the tool from Vim `:! %` can do this quickly (and repeat with `:!!`). Or just `:set autochdir`, so that the current directory within Vim always follows the currently edited file (and you can then just reference the file via `./`).

Answer (score 0):

When typing file paths in vim (as I often do for shell scripts), I find filename-complete invaluable. Simply type `<C-X><C-F>` in insert mode.

N.B. It does not work in all cases (generally vim prefers the path to be a separate WORD), but a quick edit-complete-fixup isn’t terrible.